# How to copy a row from database table and insert it to the same table using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have a codeigniter website with a table containing some values, i want to duplicate the row from the table, i did the following code:

```
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $details = $this->db->where("id", $id)->get('tbl_invoices');
    

    foreach ($details->result() as $row) {
          $this->db->insert('tbl_invoices',$row);
    }
```

however this gives me error, can anyone please tell me how to accomplis this, thanks in advance

The error is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0) VALUES (Array)' at line 1 INSERT INTO tbl_invoices (0) VALUES (Array)

Comment: ___however this gives me error___ In that case you need to show us the error or we will not know which error you are getting and then we find it difficult to be any help and then we close the question

Comment: Probably an error referring to a duplicate ID value, I am guessing ... (If so, try `$details['id'] = null;`, before you make the insert.)

Comment: @RiggsFolly i am getting You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0) VALUES (Array)' at line 1

INSERT INTO `tbl_invoices` (0) VALUES (Array)

 this error

Comment: @CBroe i tried that, still same error

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have updated my code now i get duplicate entry error for id primary key

Comment: Well @CBroe has already suggested that would be an issue. And suggested how to correct it

Comment: @RiggsFolly i actually modified code, so i got the primary key error,

Comment: YESsssss I know. So set `$row->id = NULL` or maybe `unset($row->id)` before calling the insert

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have a doubt, if i want to change value of particula field inside this code, how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unset($row->id);` in the `foreach` loop.

```
 foreach ($details->result() as $row) {
           unset($row->id);
          $this->db->insert('tbl_invoices',$row);
    }
```

Comment: it doesnt work, you should use like this unset($row->id);